# Determine the "least valuable" pair out of a set of pairs, specific constraints

Tags: algorithm, math

Sorry, I really didn't know how to word this title. I can think of costly ways of doing this, but I'd like to see if anyone can point out an elegant solution, here it is:

- I have lots of elements that are associated in pairs;
- Each element has a numeric value associated to itself, this value represents a proportion between it and the element it's paired to;
- Out of this set of pairs, every single element appears at least twice;
- An element is never paired with itself.
- Not true: *The ratios on the elements are linearly dependent*, I initially thought that would be the case, but it isn't. Nevertheless, there is a "true" ratio between pairs: if A > B and B > C, when A is paired with C it **will** be greater than C.

The idea is to pick out the pair which is the "smallest", following this rule:

Example of a set with 3 pairs:

---

**PAIR 1:** A=0.0720479 B=1.29850801

---

**PAIR 2:** C=505.0 B=0.5

---

**PAIR 3:** C=729.6079 A=0.03830566

---

By comparing two instances of the same element in two different pairs, we discard the pair where that instance was bigger. If we compare the **C** from **PAIR 3** to the **C** on **PAIR 2**, we see that **PAIR 3** is bigger, so it's discarded. Now we compare the element that appears on both **PAIR 1** and **PAIR 2**, which is **B**, since **B** is smaller on **PAIR 2**, **PAIR 1** is discarded.

The "smallest" pair in this example, is **PAIR 2**.

If the values end up being the same so that there is a draw, both pairs are accepted as the right answer.

I couldn't find much on the internet about this, mostly, I believe, because I don't know what to search for. What I'd like to is being pointed out on the right direction on how to research more about this, but ideas on elegant algorithms (pseudocode is more than fine) would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe more about this linear dependence?  It's not a simple ratio; the arithmetic in this example isn't internally consistent.

Comment: In particular, are you guaranteed that finding the least element is independent of examination order?  From what I understand of the standards so far, I can construct sets of 3-4 pairs where "least" depends on the order of pair comparison.

Comment: @Prune you are absolutely correct, I messed up and I'll edit my question. The elements are in fact not necessairly linearly dependent, I was thinking of a specific case while writing my question but it's true, not even my example is linearly dependent. About your second question, yes, I am sure order doesn't matter in this case. The conditions that will generate this values guarantee that

Comment: Great; edit the question to be more clear, and let me know whether my answer is of any help with the actual issue.

Comment: I believe the conditions you outlined are insufficient to make this question well-defined. You’ve said a pair is less than another if they have a common element and the value of the common element in the first pair is less than its value in the other pair. It’s possible that there are sets of elements which never occur in mutual pairs, so this is not a total order, thus there may be more than one “least” valuable. However the constraint you provide doesn’t guarantee asymmetry so the transitive closure of this relation is not guaranteed to be a partial order, so you may have 0 “least” pairs...

Comment: ... you could have a<b, b<c, c<d, d<a without violating your constraint on any three a,b,c, but your order in pairs would result in having a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Consider each pair as a graph edge (with properties) connecting the two variables -- each variable is a node on the graph.  Build the graph.  Now, simply pick an edge.  Pick one endpoint that has a different edge.  Compare the two pairs; delete the "losing" edge.  Continue until no more comparisons are available.  The remaining edges are your "least" set.

Comment: And simply ignore the cases where the picked nodes had no repeated elements, correct? That's along the lines of what I was thinking, but I feel like there must be a better approach.

Comment: Right; you can keep counts that make it easy to make those choices.  This is one version of a basic graph reduction algorithm.